# Are there any tests or certifications in Old English or Middle English?

Tags: resource-request, certifications

Are there any formal assessments (e.g. tests or exams) or certifications in Old English (e.g. Beowulf) or Middle English (e.g. Chaucer)? By Old English and Middle English, I am talking about the Medieval forms of English that are not always readily comprehensible to a speaker of Modern English.

Is there any way to get tested or certified in either of these languages (or any of their dialects) in any formal or meaningful way? This could involve testing reading comprehension skills, translation (e.g. translating from Old English to modern English), composition, knowledge of grammar or vocabulary, or something similar to that. I am not asking about university degrees in Medieval English Literature, Anglo-Saxon Studies, or similar programs unless the degrees are given out on the basis of passing language exams.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do a degree in English Literature if you just want to learn Old English or confirm your skills. However, I still think that individual university courses is the closest thing you can get if you want a formal exam. At some universities you may sign up for individual courses, and attending the course may not be required to sit the exam (given that you already possess the required skills).

For example, here are some relevant courses at the University of Oslo:

- [ENG2165: Old English - Language and History](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/hf/ilos/ENG2165/index.html)
- [ENG2166: Middle English, introduction](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/hf/ilos/ENG2166/index.html)

You may also want to take a look at one of the [previous exams in Old English](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/hf/ilos/ENG2154/Eksamensoppgaver/eng2154.h14.pdf) to see what kind of skills it tests.